# Verification of proof for Baby Rudin 3.19

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Inspired by this post:
[Proof that if $s_n \leq t_n$ for $n \geq N$, then $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n \leq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} t_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176093/proof-that-if-s-n-leq-t-n-for-n-geq-n-then-liminf-n-rightarrow-infty)

As a beginner self-learner, I wanted to see if I could write a proof that's self contained with respect to what I've learnt in Rudin thus far.

Thanks in advance if you can be bothered to vet my proof.

(This is the $\sup$ case, and $s^* = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n = \sup{E_s}$ just like in Rudin.)

**Theorem**

$$\forall n\ge N,s_n\le t_n \implies s^* \le t^*$$
**Proof**

If $s^* = -\infty$ or $t^* = +\infty$, the result follows. Hence assume $s^* \neq -\infty $ and $ t^* \neq +\infty.$

> *Lemma:* $s^*,t^* \in  \mathbb{R}$.  (As opposed to $\mathbb{R} \cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}.)$
>
> *Proof*: Assume $t^* = -\infty$. By Rudin Theorem 3.17 (a), $t^*\in E_t$ so that $E_t = \{-\infty\}.$
> Then for any subsequence $\{t_{n_k}\} $,$\{t_{n_k}\} $ must be bounded above (otherwise it would contain a subsequence that approached $+\infty$). By Definition 3.15 if $\{t_{n_k}\} $ does not approach $-\infty$ then $\{t_{n_k}\} $ contains a subsequence that is bounded below. Then this subsequence is both bounded above and below. Then $\{t_{n_k}\} $ contains a convergent subsequence.
> Hence $\forall \{t_{n_k}\},t_{n_k}\rightarrow t^*=-\infty.$Then for any real $M$,$$\exists K, k\ge K \implies t_{n_k} \le M.$$  For any $\{s_{n_k}\}$, let $n_p =\min\{n_k|n_k\ge N\}$. Then for any real $M$,$$k\ge \max(p,K) \implies s_{n_k}\le t_{n_k} \le M.$$
> Hence $s_{n_k} \rightarrow -\infty$ for all $\{s_{n_k}\}$ so that $E_s = \{-\infty\}$, contradicting our assumption that $s^* \neq -\infty $. A similar argument shows $s^*\neq +\infty.$

Suppose $s^* > t^*$. Then by 3.17 (b) $$\exists G, n\ge G \implies t_{n} \lt s^*$$
Then by 3.17(a) $s^*\in E_s$ so that there exists $\{s_{n_k}\} $ such that $s_{n_k}\rightarrow s^*$.  Let $n_q =\min\{n_k|n_k\ge G\}$. Then$$k\ge \max(p,q) \implies s_{n_k}\le t_{n_k} \lt s^*$$ Since $s_{n_k}\rightarrow s^*$ we have $$\forall \epsilon > 0,\exists r, k\ge r \implies |s^*-s_{n_k}| < \epsilon$$ Then $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $$k\ge \max(p,q,r) \implies |s^*-t_{n_k}|\le|s^*-s_{n_k}| \lt \epsilon$$ so that $$ t_{n_k}\rightarrow s^* > t^* = \sup{E_t}$$ which is a contradiction.